# Unlink VirtualBox VM Clone from VM Parent

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a VirtualBox virtual machine that some time ago I cloned. I began to use more the clone and now I would delete the initial virtual machine as it occupies space. But the storage of the clone (settings->storage->controller) points to the VDI file of the initial virtual machine.

Is there a way to unlink the initial virtual machine from the clone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there is no direct way to unlink them.

I exported and imported back the cloned virtual machine to create a new one. In the process I used an external hard drive for extra space.

From the VirtualBox Manager I used "File → Export Appliance". This generated an OVF file. From "File → Import Appliance" I created a new virtual machine.